# Entity Framework Code First: One-to-One where PK is a FK

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I'd like to map a *one-to-one* relationship using **Entity Framework 5 Code First** like this:

```
public class User
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
     public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Note that database **Profile table** schema has a **primary key** `UserId` that's a **foreign key** to *Users* table.

I'd like to know if I can avoid an *artificial identifier* in **Profiles table**.

Thank you in advance!

---

---

**UPDATE**

Well, it seems that both answers of **Eranga** and **hvd** are useful. With some own contribution, I got a transaction creating an user with the belonging profile successfully.

- **hvd** => *There's no need of the artificial identifier in the object model*.
- **Erlanga** => Your approach works BUT *it forces you to have an [Id] column in the database*.

Does anyone found a way of avoiding the artificial identifier even in the database table?

Comment: @hvd It's all about avoiding to have an useless **Id** column in **Profiles** table. I just want to have **UserId**, since users will have a single profile and this isn't going to change in the future.

Comment: I realised that after re-reading, which is why I had deleted my comment :)

Comment: Is it okay to have an explicit `OwnerId` property? If you set up `Owner` as corresponding to the `OwnerId` foreign key field, and mark `OwnerId` as the key, it should work (and does in my situation).

Comment: Well, if there's no other way of doing, it can be "ok". But I was wondering if there's an approach which allows us to avoid this "OwnerId" property.

Comment: @hvd BTW, if you can post a full answer about your approach it'll be appreciated.

Comment: Will do when I can, I don't have the code in front of me in which I do that.

Comment: About your update: that's exactly the reason I do use foreign key properties, to allow further customisation, to specify by what name `OwnerId` is stored in the database. Sorry, I don't know if it's possible to specify that without actually having the property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One to One Relationship on Primary Key with Entity Framework Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339951/one-to-one-relationship-on-primary-key-with-entity-framework-code-first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fluent API to map  the relationship.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>()
        .HasRequired(p => p.Owner)
        .WithOptional();
 }
```

**Update:**

One-to-One relationships can only be modeled in using the mapping technique called "Shared Primary Key". That is the PK of the dependent entity is also an FK. There is no *artificial identifier* involved in the dependent entity(ie. `Profile`) because it refers to the PK values of independent entity (ie. `User`)

Comment: And you don't need to configure a key for that?

Comment: And sorry, how does EF knows which is the DB column name of the Owner?

Comment: Other point is I need it **required**. I've been checking MSDN documentation and I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671273(v=vs.103).aspx (WithRequiredDependent) which seems to fit better. BTW I understand that EF can discover the column name by convention, but what if I don't want to use its convention and I require a one of mine? Is this possible?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer The `Id` property(ie. Primary Key) of the `Profile` entity is taken as the FK.

Comment: Ok. But as I said in my question, is there any way of avoiding this artificial identifier?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It's not an artificial identifier. The user id is stored in the FK. Its is a FK and PK at the same time.

Comment: Ah, ok. The confusion was "The `Id` property [...]". Ok, let me try everything in some minutes. BTW note that the relationship isn't "Optional". It's required. So I guess I need to configure that by calling "WithRequiredDependent".

Comment: This isn't working: **Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Profile' and 'User'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.**

Comment: I got it working, but now I've other problem, but it's unrelated with current question.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I tell EF that PK/FK is "UserId" instead of just "Id". It's the final step to get it fully working!

Comment: Yeah, but I when I try to use that concept, the INSERT generated by Entity Framework includes an [Id] column that's not present in the database, because the PK/FK is "UserId" in Profiles table.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it (classes renamed to match your situation):

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
}

var userConfiguration = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
userConfiguration.HasKey(u => u.Id);
userConfiguration.HasOptional(u => u.Profile).WithRequired(p => p.Owner);

var profileConfiguration = modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>();
profileConfiguration.HasKey(p => p.OwnerId);
profileConfiguration.HasRequired(p => p.Owner).WithOptional(u => u.Profile);
```

The `HasOptional(u => u.Profile).WithRequired(p => p.Owner)` tells EF that `p.Owner` should be mapped to the primary key, which is `OwnerId`. You *should* be able to make this work without `OwnerId` or `Profile` properties, but this is what works for me, and allows for further configuration of those properties.

Comment: Eranga approach works. You can avoid that "OwnerId" property! Take in account!! :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Glad to hear that. Did you end up having an "Id" property instead of a "UserId" property (with otherwise the same meaning), or did you actually manage to get EF to use a different database field name without a property?

Comment: Thanks! I got what I wanted: Profiles table has a PK+FK "UserId". There's no other "Id". :D

Comment: I've attempted this solution only to get a SQL error "SqlException: Invalid column name 'Source'." Any thoughts where this might be coming from?  (It's only when using the navigation property)