# Creating a 1:1 relationship using EF CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am battling with EF code first and trying to map a 1:1 relationship with no joy.

Basically a user can have a userdetail.

I am setting primary keys on both tables.On my UserDetail table has field UserId I am trying to use as the FK.

```
public class User:BaseModel
{
    public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
public class UserDetail:BaseModel
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserDetailName { get; set; }
}
public class BaseModel{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I try using the `add-migration` command I get this error

> UserDetail_User_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'UserDetail_User_Source' in relationship 'UserDetail_User'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

What do I need to do to get this working? Surely this shouldnt be that difficult?

> Update below based on comment from @steve-green

I configured the fluentapi like steve suggested

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                    .HasRequired(t => t.UserDetail)
                    .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.User);
```

however the generated migration step looks wrong to me

```
  CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserDetails",
            c => new
                {
                    UserDetailId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserDetailName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserDetailId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserDetailId)
            .Index(t => t.UserDetailId);
```

The FK is configured as `UserDetailId` shouldnt it be `UserId`?

Slightly modified model

```
public class UserDetail
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserDetailName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One to One Relationship on Primary Key with Entity Framework Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339951/one-to-one-relationship-on-primary-key-with-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: Thats slightly different. I don't have ability on my model to add the [ForeignKey] attribute on my primary key. As all of my models inherit from a base model class with the  primary key. I will update my code example

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the attribute

```
  [ForeignKey("User")
```

in UserDetail. Also, i would add

```
  int UserDetailId
```

to User

That should then work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a base table, then you can't do it with annotations because (as you mention) the key on the required dependent needs to be a foreign key. You will need fluent api code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>() 
    .HasRequired(t => t.UserDetail) 
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.User);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToRequired